# c# Как к Binding добавить статичный текст

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, binding

Как для биндинга добавить дополнительный статичный текст? Т.е. `String.Format("Цена: {0}",myBinding)`

В параметрах `SetBinding` принимается к сожалению только к чему мы привязываем и что мы привязываем(биндинг), как это модифицируется?

```
            var name = new Label() { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start };
            name.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Name"));
```

Используется в Xamarin, для создания пользовательских ячеек для ListView

```
public class SessionCell : ViewCell
    {
        public SessionCell()
        {
            var name = new Label() { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start };
            var price = new Label() { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand };
            var time = new Label() { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill };

            name.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Name"));
            price.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Price"));
            time.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Time"));

            name.TextColor = Color.DarkCyan;
            price.TextColor = Color.DarkGreen;

            var horizontalLayout = new StackLayout()
            {
                Children = {
                    new StackLayout(){ Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, Children = {name, price } },
                    time
                }
            };

            View = horizontalLayout;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Интересно, а почему так много людей делают привязку через код? Незнание, или есть в этом хоть какой то смысл? Ведь задать в xaml у нужных контролов `{Binding MyProperty}` и один раз задать где нужно `DataContext` эффективней, чем сотни раз в коде прописывать `SetBinding`...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я не пользуюсь XAML, пишу только на c#, и незнание данной тематики тоже играет роль

Comment: Интересный вы человек. Теги надо было раньше нужные проставлять, и в вопросе уточнять о построении какой программы идет речь, а не постфактум, после ответа.

Comment: @Bulson прошу прощения, некомпетентность не позволила составить вопрос в полной мере с самого начала. Считал, что Binding независим от платформ или чего либо ещё. Что это просто технология C#

Comment: OK, внимательнее, пожалуйста,  к простановке нужных тегов относитесь.

Answer (score 1):

Если актуально еще, то вот: `label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("NotifyCounter",stringFormat: "To remove all({0:N0}) click button"));`